# Copy state from one contract to another

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, openzeppelin-sdk

I am experimenting with the zeppelin os upgradeable contracts but what I only need for my contract is to keep one specific state array when I deploy to another address. Avoiding proxy issues, upgrade frameworks and such, is there a way to do this manually somehow?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a rough sketch to give you some ideas about partitioning concerns into a simple upgradable structure.

- First, a very simple `Owned` contract for *transferable* access control.
- Then a `Keeper` contract that is meant to hold the array during upgrades.
- This version of `Replaceable` deploys it's own `Keeper` to get started. By doing so, `Keeper` recognizes that `Replaceable` is the owner, not the developer.
- To actually replace `Replaceable`, you would first deploy a new version of it. In the replacement case, the constructor would not create a new `Keeper`. Instead, you would pass in the address of the *existing* `Keeper` and use `keeper = Keeper(keeperAddress);` Of course, `Keeper` will initially ignore the new contract because it doesn't "own" the data store. You tell the old `Replaceable` to pull the trigger and transfer ownership away from itself.

-

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Owned {

    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function changeOwner(address newOwner) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
        owner = newOwner;
        return true;
    }
}

contract Keeper is Owned {

    bytes32[] public array;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function appendArray(bytes32 value) public onlyOwner returns(uint arrayLength) {
        uint length = array.push(value);
        return length;
    }
}

contract Replacable is Owned {

    Keeper keeper;

    constructor() public {
        keeper = new Keeper();
    }

    function getKeeperAddress() public view returns(address keeperAddress) {
        return address(keeper);
    }

    function appendInKeeper(bytes32 value) public onlyOwner returns(uint arrayLength) {
        return keeper.appendArray(value);
    }

    function inspectInKeeper(uint row) public view returns(bytes32 value) {
        return keeper.array(row);
    }

    function appointNewReplacable(address newContract) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
        return keeper.changeOwner(newContract);
    }

}
```

I left out quite a few details to keep the example on point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks it helps. Although this is a bit complicated and would make the zeppelinos option compelling for upgrades. I was thinking of something more of like make a function that spits out all the array and then have it passed as an argument to the new contract constructor manually